# cannot convert int to int c++

Tags: c++, int

I'm trying to overload operator "<<" in c++. I have a class called TCalendario, with 3 privates int attributes, and 3 public getters to return this variables in public mode, but when I try to save the return value of the getter in another int variable, i can't compile. The mensage error is:

"cannot convert 'TCalendario::Dia' from type 'int (TCalendario::)()' to type 'int'"

Private attributes:

```
private:
int dia, mes, anyo
```

And getters:

```
int TCalendario::Dia()
{
    return dia;
}
int TCalendario::Mes()
{
    return mes;
}
int TCalendario::Anyo()
{
    return anyo;
}
```

The code that crashes when I try to compile is:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &x, TCalendario &c)
{
    int day=c.Dia;
    int month=c.Mes;
    int year=c.Anyo;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add `()`. That message is telling you everything you need to know.

Comment: you forgot the return statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call a method without arguments, you need to put empty braces, like this:

```
int day=c.Dia();
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `()` in function call

```
int day=c.Dia();
int month=c.Mes();
int year=c.Anyo();
```